# Database query in Drupal

Tags: sql, database, drupal, select

So I have this sql code in Drupal:

```
$query = db_query('SELECT wpv.nid, n.title, AVG(vote) average FROM {wp_votes} wpv
    LEFT JOIN {node} n on wpv.nid = n.nid
    GROUP BY wpv.nid
    ORDER BY average DESC
    LIMIT 3');
```

It works just fine, but I need to write it with db_select:

```
$query2 = db_select('wp_votes','wpv');
$query2->join('node','n','wpv.nid = n.nid');
$query2->fields('wpv',array('nid','vote'));
$query2->fields('n',array('title'));
$rez = $query2->execute()->fetchAll();
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can get the average vote(votes are 1,2 or 3).
How do i rewrite the part with AVG(vote). I tried with addEXpression('AVG(vote)') but it didn't work as expected, I got the average for all the entries, not just for those with the same id.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to make sure you understand that unless you're building queries dynamically you should always use db_query.  There is a common misconception that you should always use db_select, which simply isn't true. There is extra overhead in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AVG you need to use [addExpression()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddExpression/7) and groupBy and you will have something like this

```
<?php
$query2 = db_select('wp_votes','wpv');
$query2->join('node','n','wpv.nid = n.nid');
$query2->fields('wpv',array('nid','vote'));
$query2->fields('n',array('title'));
$alias = $query2->addExpression('AVG(vote)', 'average');
$query2->groupBy('wpv.nid');
$query2->sortBy($alias, 'DESC');
$rez = $query2->execute()->fetchAll();
```

I'm not sure about sorting by $alias, but theoretical, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Still needed the groupBy, and it wass addExpresion('AVG(vote)','average');

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you forgot to use 

`$query->groupBy('wpv.nid');`

that's why you got the AVG for all records.